# Noun phrase as an adjective

Tags: adjectives, nouns

> This testimonial I accordingly received in about a month, forwarded a copy of it to Mrs. Fairfax, and got that lady’s reply, stating that she was satisfied, and fixing that day **fortnight as the period** for my assuming the post of governess in her house.
>   (Jane Eyre)

Is the highlighted noun phrase the case of a complement for the noun – an adjective function?

Comment: @Kiamlaluno's answer is correct in traditional grammar. Prof. Aarts would probably regard *as the period ...* as an Object-related predicative complement licensed by *fix*: the idiom is *fix [DATE] [as OCCASION]*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"That day fortnight" is the direct object for *fixing*; it means "two weeks starting from that day." "As the period for my assuming the post of governess in her house" is an adverbial phrase that modifies *fixing*.

"Fortnight as the period" doesn't have the function of adjective.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this usage of *fortnight* was ever common. It's practically unheard of today, though we do still use the format with *week*. I'm not sure about modern Americans, but to most British native speakers...

> "(I'll see you) [Monday week](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you%20monday%20week%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)"

...means *I'll see you on Monday **a week after** the first Monday following today*. By the same principle, Jane means **a fortnight after** "that day"*, but at the very least you'd raise a few eyebrows if you used the form today (many native speakers wouldn't just find it "odd"; they wouldn't understand you at all).

The sentence also sounds stilted because of the way it uses the word *period*. Jane is actually specifying *the **date on which** she will assume the post of governess*, rather than the "period" between the date of speaking and the date she starts work. In modern English she'd say *...as the **date** for assuming the post*.

Comment: In [**BE**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fortnight&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=), *fortnight* was trending up when JE was written, peaked in the early 1930s and has been in decline since the mid-1950s. *Xday fortnight* and *Xday week* have marched pretty much in lockstep since about [**1860**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tuesday+fortnight%2CTuesday+week&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=). This use of *period* is not a 'period' thing but appears to be idiolectal to Brontë: *OED 1* doesn't acknowledge it.

Comment: @StoneyB: I wasn't really concerned with any possible decline in prevalence of the actual word *fortnight*. My point was that usages like *"We'll meet again Friday fortnight"* sounded really odd to me (whereas *"We'll meet Friday **week**"* sounds perfectly normal). In fact, checking Google Books more carefully, it seems this particular usage of *fortnight* was still reasonably common a couple of centuries ago, tailing off rapidly through the latter half of C19.